# How to make online scoreboard for html5 game?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a html5 game. Which support online score board. And port it to other mobile plattform.

So how can i do online scoreboard for this game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An online scoreboard usually requires a database, and some knowledge of a server side scripting language. If you're planning on learning these things, I suggest a MySQL database and PHP. If you already know how to use these, there are many tutorials which a google search will give you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Google App Engine https://developers.google.com/appengine/

it easy to connect to database in clouds, and read write in memcache.